# Lagrange Interpolation Polynomials and functions of Matrices

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, lagrange-interpolation

Say we are given a matrix $A$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$ with minimal polynomial $\mu_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2(\lambda-1)^2$ so we know $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$ where $m \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 4}$. Then if we were to find a formula for $A^n$, we let $h(z)=z^n$, we want to find a degree 3 polynomial

$$
g(z) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1\cdot z + \alpha_2\cdot z^2 + \alpha_3\cdot z^3.
$$
We known that $g(0) = h(0), \;g'(0) = h'(0),\; g(1) = h(1),\; g'(1) = h'(1)$ (from our minimal polynomial). This gives $g(z) = (3-m)z^2 + (m-2)z^3$. Does this mean that
$$
A^m = (3-m)\cdot A^2 + (m-2)\cdot A^3, \; m\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 4}.
$$
Does this formula work, I'm unsure of the logic behind Lagrange Interpolations.

---

Just to make sure my computation is correct we get 4 equations
$$
1=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 \\
m= \alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 + 3\alpha_3 \\
0 = \alpha_0\\
0 = \alpha_1
$$
thus $a_3 = m-2, \; a_2 = 3-m$.

Answer (score 1):

You should have made an error in your computations as $\mu_A(z) = z^4-2z^3+z^2$ and therefore

$$z^4= 1 \cdot \mu(z) + 2 z^3 - z^2$$ which doesn't match

$$(4-m)\cdot z^2 + (m-3)\cdot z^3$$ for $m=4$.

Your error is that $h_m^\prime(z) = \left(z^m\right)^\prime = m z^{m-1}$. So $m= \alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 + 3\alpha_3$ and not $m-1= \alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 + 3\alpha_3$.

And your overall logic is correct. You are doing the [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#Euclidean_division) of $h^m$ by $\mu_a$, i.e.

$$h_m = q_m \mu_A + r_m$$ with $\deg r_m <\deg \mu_A$.

As $\mu_A(0)=\mu_A(1)=\mu_A^\prime(0)=\mu_A^\prime(1)=0$, the equations you used are correct to find $r_m(z) = (m-2) z^3 + (3-m) z^2$.

*Note: as $h$ ang $g$ depend on $m$, better to use indices to name them.*

Comment: I know I've made an error, I was hoping you could point out where that error is as I can't figure it out.

Comment: Write down your computations in the question. It will ease the reader to point out the error. By the way, doing so, it is likely that you'll find the error by your own.

Comment: @JohnMiller You made an error in the computation of the derivative of $z \mapsto z^m$. See updated answer above.

Comment: You were correct I had a basic algebraic error, but more importantly does my new function work for $A$ as I didn't care much for the algebra just the logic.

Comment: @JohnMiller Some additional points in the answer.